# How do I manipulate/move object with generic rigidbody constraints while in playback to see effect

Tags: rigidbody

I was watching this older video on how to do a ragdoll effect.

https://youtu.be/GaZAI8RIq0Q?t=589

At about 9:50 into the video, he tests the effect of the rigidbody constraints by moving one of the objects while playing the animation.  I'm using Blender 2.8, so maybe this way easier in the older versions?  Is there a setting I need to change?  Just pressing spacebar to start and G to move the object does not do what this guy does in the video.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out 10 minutes later.  You have to enable "Animated" under the rigid body settings.  Then you can move around the object during the playback and it will interact with everything in the scene.